# Creating A New SharePoint Service Admin Account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, service-account, farm-admin

We want to create a new SharePoint Service Admin account that will have Farm administrator privileges exactly the same as the existing Farm account.

[EDIT]
I need this to work for 2007, 2010 and 2013 environments.

The reason for this is so we can run a third part tool under this account that runs on another server without having to give direct access to our SharePoint servers.

What are the set of steps we need to follow to give a service account the same permissions in SharePoint as our existing Farm admin account?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the account to the Farm Administrators Group in Central Admin?

1. Open Central Admin.
2. Under **Security** click on the link **Manage the farm administrators group**.
3. Click New to add the user to the group.

Second step:

1. Open SharePoint Powershell prompt
2. Run Add-SPShellAdmin -username domain\account

Comment: yes.  The account has been added to that group.  We are still seeing issues when the tool runs under that new account.  When we run it under the existing Farm admin account then it works fine.

Comment: I know an account get additional permissions when you add the account as shell admin, see Add-SPShellAdmin. If that is just for Powershell or not I don't know, try it and let us know of any change.

Comment: I just realized a wrote a blog about this 4 years ago :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattlind/archive/2011/05/13/add-spshelladmin-complicated-by-accounts.aspx

Comment: Add-SPShellAdmin is a 2010 and 2013 command only.  Following the instructions above does not work in a 2007 environment to set up a new account.  When I run a stsadm -o migrateuser command under the newly created farm admin acccount it fails but works under the old farm admin account.